# JavaFX: Finding out when a Window/Stage has completed "un-minimizing"

Tags: java, javafx

I was attempting to make a popup overlay window.

```
public class TestPopup extends PopupControl {
    private final Window owner;

    private final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.RED);

    private boolean isPopupTemporarilyHidden = false;
    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> parentFocusChangeListener;

    private final NumberBinding aX;
    private final NumberBinding aY;

    protected TestPopup(Window owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;

        parentFocusChangeListener = (focusedProperty, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
            if (owner.isShowing())
                return;
            // Hide the popup when the owner window loses focus
            if (!isFocused) {
                hide();
                isPopupTemporarilyHidden = true;
            }
            // Show again when the owner window re-gains focus
            else if (isPopupTemporarilyHidden) {
                show();
                isPopupTemporarilyHidden = false;
            }
        };

        final WeakChangeListener<Boolean> weakListener = new WeakChangeListener<>(parentFocusChangeListener);
        owner.focusedProperty().addListener(weakListener);

        setSkin(new Skin<Skinnable>() {
            @Override
            public Skinnable getSkinnable() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Node getNode() {
                return rect;
            }

            @Override
            public void dispose() {}
        });

        // Trying to adjust popup location whenever the owner window moves
        aX = owner.xProperty().add(owner.getScene().xProperty()).add(10);
        aY = owner.yProperty().add(owner.getScene().yProperty()).add(10);

        // anchorX and anchorY are read-only - cannot bind
        aX.addListener(ax -> setAnchorX(aX.getValue().doubleValue()));
        aY.addListener(ay -> setAnchorY(aY.getValue().doubleValue()));
    }

    public void showPopup() {
        show(owner, owner.getX() + owner.getScene().getX() + 10, owner.getY() + owner.getScene().getY() + 10);
    }
}
```

If I minimize the window, and then un-minimize it via the taskbar, the popup (with red rectangle) will show up on screen before the owner window slowly animates in. I am using Windows 10, so natively windows do have an animation when they are being un-minimized.

I have also tried reading the value of `Stage.iconifiedProperty()` but it seems that the value changes to `false` before the animation finishes. Is there any way I could make the popup show *after* the animation finishes?

A side question: there is a noticeable lag in the popup when I drag the owner window around the screen. Is there anyway I could do to reduce the lag?

Comment: The animation speed is going to be OS-specific and I doubt Java would have a way of knowing whether animations are even taking place. Maybe you could just add a timed delay before showing the popup to account for the animation time?

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks for your reply. I was guessing along the line too... but I wanted to see if anyone could find anything in the API (maybe glass level) that could effectively mean the same thing.